# How to configure exist-db app in apache virtual host?

Tags: apache, exist-db

On apache server I'm trying to do the following:
myapp1.mydomain.com should open an exist-db app
myapp2.mydomain.com should open another exist-db app and so on.
I've read the documentation and tried all the solutions given here, but unfortunately I still can't get it work.
I have this in apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xxx:80>
ServerName myapp1.mydomain.com

ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost on

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/myapp1/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/myapp1/

ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /exist /
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain localhost myapp1.mydomain.com

RewriteEngine       on
RewriteRule         ^/(.*)$     /$1   [PT]
<VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that when I write "myapp1.mydomain.com" in the bowser, it gives this:

```
Problem accessing /exist/apps/myapp1/exist/apps/myapp1/index.html. Reason:

Document /db/apps/myapp1/exist/apps/myapp1/index.html not found
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong, so any help would be appreciated!

P.S. answering the question by @adamretter - yes, there's a controller.xql:

```
xquery version "3.0";

import module namespace login-helper="http://exist-db.org/apps/dashboard/login-helper" at "modules/login-helper.xql";
import module namespace login="http://exist-db.org/xquery/login" at "resource:org/exist/xquery/modules/persistentlogin/login.xql";

declare variable $exist:path external;
declare variable $exist:resource external;
declare variable $exist:controller external;
declare variable $exist:prefix external;
declare variable $exist:root external;

if ($exist:path eq "/") then
    (: forward root path to index.xql :)
    <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
        <redirect url="index.html"/>
    </dispatch>
else if (ends-with($exist:resource, ".html")) then
    (: the html page is run through view.xql to expand templates :)
    <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
        <view>
            <forward url="{$exist:controller}/modules/view.xql"/>
        </view>
        <error-handler>
            <forward url="{$exist:controller}/error-page.html" method="get"/>
            <forward url="{$exist:controller}/modules/view.xql"/>
        </error-handler>
    </dispatch>
(: Resource paths starting with $shared are loaded from the shared-resources app :)
else if (contains($exist:path, "/$shared/")) then
    <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
        <forward url="/shared-resources/{substring-after($exist:path, '/$shared/')}">
            <set-header name="Cache-Control" value="max-age=3600, must-revalidate"/>
        </forward>
    </dispatch>

(: images, css are contained in the top /resources/ collection. :)
(: Relative path requests from sub-collections are redirected there :)
else if (contains($exist:path, "/resources/")) then
    <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
        <forward url="{$exist:controller}/resources/{substring-after($exist:path, '/resources/')}">
            <set-header name="Cache-Control" value="max-age=3600, must-revalidate"/>
        </forward>
    </dispatch>

else
    (: everything else is passed through :)
    <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
        <cache-control cache="yes"/>
    </dispatch>
```

Comment: So... the exact address you are entering in the browser is "http://myapp1.mydomain.com"?

Comment: Yes, and of course "mydomain" is replaced with the name of my domain and "myapp1" - with the name of my app.

Comment: Do you have any `controller.xql` in the mix?

Comment: Yes, I just added it at the end of the question.